# Cinnamon for CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos-6, cinnamon

I was trying to install Cinnamon from Source code in a CentOS v.6.4.

Unfortunately, I was stumbling upon dependencies that were becoming weird each and every time.
Some of them, I tried to build, but didn't work. They needed things like GTK+ of certain version that wasn't available for CentOS.

Do you know if there is anyway to install Cinnamon in CentOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS (which is derived from RHEL) are still on Gnome 2.  Since Cinnamon is based on Gnome 3, I would think that you would have an uphill battle getting it to work on CentOS.  If you are looking to have Cinnamon work on a RPM based distro, then you should consider Fedora, OpenSuse or Mageia.

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cinnamon-desktop-on-centos-6-5-a-4175495412/

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=61&t=130167

http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/?page_id=61

Answer (score 1):

Cinnamon 2.0 is now available in CentOS 7. You can install it from the epel repository.
You can also install the latest Cinnamon 2.8 from epel-testing:

```
yum install --enablerepo=epel-testing cinnamon*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use an [RPM search engine](http://rpm.pbone.net/) to find a [`cinnamon` RPM](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=26&dist=0&size=1513965&name=cinnamon-1.4-1.src.rpm) and install that way. Just download the RPM and install using

```
rpm -ivh cinnamon-1.4-1.src.rpm
```